# VBScript To Run Excel Macro

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am attempting to run this script

```
if WScript.Arguments.Count < 1 Then   
WScript.Echo "Drop file on to me to process."   
Wscript.QuitEnd If
Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
Set oVBC = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents oVBC.Import("C:\Test\Test.bas") 
oBook.Application.Run "Test" 
WScript.Echo "Done"
```

The name of the macro inside of the Test.bas file is Test() and the file is located at C:\Test\Test.bas - now anytime I try to drag a .xlsx file on top of the .vbscript I get an error that reads

> Syntax error
> 800A03EA
> Microsoft VBScript Compilation error

What needs to be altered in this script to remedy that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Wscript.QuitEnd If` Needs to be fixed to

`Wscript.Quit
End If`

`Set oVBC = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents oVBC.Import("C:\Test\Test.bas")` to

`Set oVBC = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents 
 oVBC.Import("C:\Test\Test.bas")`

Comment: Changing that syntax gives me an error on line 7 - Expected End Of statement.

Comment: `Set oVBC = oBook.VBProject.VBComponents oVBC.Import("C:\Test\Test.bas")` Try bringing `oVBC.Import("C:\Test\Test.bas")` down a line.

Comment: Yes, that got it!  It produces the file as needed but I get an Unknown Runtime Error as well?

Comment: -- would prefer to avoid just a random on error resume next if possible

Comment: It does not show me the line.  It seems the script is run to completion as the file is generated just as I need.  I don't understand the error, haha

Comment: Hmm it's hard to tell... Could you open the macro in developer and step through line by line to find where it's hitting the runtime error?

Comment: How would I open in developer?  I write using Notepad++ and save with .vbs extension